# VBA : Error using Range.Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this formula

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Range(formrange).Formula = "=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B2);WEEKDAY(DATE($B$38;$B$37;B2);2)>5;DAY(EOMONTH(DATE($B$38;$B$37;B$3);0))<B2);0;IF(C2=""Y"";0,5;1))"
```

And am having the following error

```
Run-time error "1004"
Application-denied or object-defined error
```

Would you guys have an idea what that is?

Comment: Replace the semicolons with commas. `Formula` expects US syntax.

Comment: I think your IF statement at the end has one too many arguments also

Comment: @chase no the `0,5` in american English would be `0.5`, that will need to be changed also, though.  So, good catch.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah, interesting. Thank you for sharing

Comment: Weird how international editions of Excel use different function names and punctuation - but formulas entered in VBA still must be in the US format.

Comment: @Rory Wow thanks guys, so the formula works on plain Excel but has to be changed within VBA. Thanks Bill Gates ! lol PS : Rory post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @dnep Not that weird - makes it a lot easier to program a workbook that could end up being used anywhere in the world! :)

Comment: Sure, but it is a brutal violation of least surprise principle. It would be better if cell formulas were always in US format, or could be switched US/local with a click or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Range.Formula` property needs a formula string in the same format it would be entered into a cell on a computer with US regional settings. So for this example you need:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Range(formrange).Formula = "=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B2),WEEKDAY(DATE($B$38,$B$37,B2),2)>5,DAY(EOMONTH(DATE($B$38,$B$37,B$3),0))<B2),0,IF(C2=""Y"",0.5,1))"
```